# Crash dump shows a thrown exception but there is a try-catch that's supposed to catch it

Tags: c#, exception

A customer is reporting IIS crashes and provided a crash dump file.  I cannot reproduce the issue (even if I pass a bad numStr) and am very confused by what I've found so far.  Here's the relevant code which catches all exceptions:

```
public class NetUtils
{
    public static int stringToInt(string numStr, int defValue)
    {
        int num = defValue;
        try
        {
            num = Int32.Parse(numStr);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return num;
    }
```

Here's the Windbg output which tells me that a FormatException got past the catch block.

```
0:021> !pe
Exception object: 0272e1b8
Exception type: System.FormatException
Message: Input string was not in a correct format.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
<none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131537
0:021> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x1598 (21)
ESP       EIP     
0ffddf80 77e4bee7 [HelperMethodFrame: 0ffddf80] 
0ffde024 79a0e4a8 System.Number.StringToNumber(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, NumberBuffer ByRef, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, Boolean)
0ffde04c 792ef2d8 System.Number.ParseInt32(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
0ffde114 02360a3b AXSWebSvc.NetUtils.stringToInt(System.String, Int32)
0ffde140 023624ab AXSWebSvc.AXSExchangeSvc.search(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
0ffde494 79e71b4c [CustomGCFrame: 0ffde494] 
0ffde45c 79e71b4c [GCFrame: 0ffde45c] 
0ffde478 79e71b4c [GCFrame: 0ffde478] 
0ffde65c 79e71b4c [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0ffde65c] System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(System.Object, System.Object[], System.SignatureStruct ByRef, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
0ffde6cc 792d52d8 System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
0ffde71c 792d5086 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean)
0ffde758 792d4f6e System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0ffde778 65dd912b System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[])
0ffde79c 65e1094e System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
0ffde7dc 65e10625 System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
0ffde80c 65e10fb7 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)
0ffde820 660ad8f6 System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
0ffde854 6608132c System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)
0ffde894 6608c3a3 System.Web.HttpApplication+ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)
0ffde8e4 660808ac System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
0ffde900 66083e1c System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest)
0ffde934 66083ac3 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest)
0ffde944 66082c5c System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr, Int32)
0ffdeb58 79f68c4e [ContextTransitionFrame: 0ffdeb58] 
0ffdeb8c 79f68c4e [GCFrame: 0ffdeb8c] 
0ffdece8 79f68c4e [ComMethodFrame: 0ffdece8]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that all of stringToInt?  Also, are you sure your customer has the same version of your software?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same version of the code that is deployed at the customer ?

Comment: When you say IIS crashes, do you mean that the whole web server goes down, or is this exception reported on the front end?

Comment: try looking at this in dotPeek or other decompiler, maybe there is some weird optimalization?

Comment: Looks to me like you should get in touch with a company called "axs-one" and work the support channels they have.  Their code is doing *something* to break the CLR exception guarantees.

Comment: @JonSenchyna,  yes that is all of stringToInt.  And yes, I've checked the version numbers to make sure that we have the same version of the code. `

Comment: @Paddy, yes, they are reporting the web server goes down and provided crash dumps and other connections get disconnected.

Comment: @ariscris - Something odd happening then - where does this get called from?

Comment: @0lukasz0, I used dotPeek to check the released dll with their version number and it had the same code for stringToInt().

Comment: @Paddy, AXSWebSvc.dll is a .NET web service.  The customer has their own code that calls it. The system periodically (at high loads they say) crashes.

Comment: @ariscris - not an answer, but have you had a look at this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/04/27/asp-net-2-0-crash-case-study-unhandled-exceptions.aspx

Comment: In addition, if you could add some more of your code leading up to this call, we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor your code and avoid using exceptions for control flow. You should be using `TryParse`:

```
public static int StringToInt(string numStr, int defValue)
{
    int num;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(numStr, out num)) { return defValue; }
    return num;
}
```

It's strange that the exception isn't being caught, and that definitely shouldn't be happening. Perhaps your customer is using a different version of the product than you have the source code for.

Comment: Correct, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @dris: See the note on the bottom.  That's probably the root cause.